# How to upload file using nestjs-graphql-fastify server and how to test such feature?

Tags: graphql, nestjs, fastify

I struggle to upload .csv file to nestjs-graphql-fastify server. Tried following code:

```
  @Mutation(() => Boolean)
  async createUsers(
    @Args({ name: 'file', type: () => GraphQLUpload })
    { createReadStream, filename }: FileUpload,
  ): Promise<boolean> {
    try {
      // backend logic . . .
    } catch {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

but all I get when testing with postman is this response:

```
{
    "statusCode": 415,
    "code": "FST_ERR_CTP_INVALID_MEDIA_TYPE",
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "message": "Unsupported Media Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------511769018912715357993837"
}
```

Developing with code-first approach.

Update: Tried to use fastify-multipart but issue still remains. What has changed is response in postman:

```
POST body missing, invalid Content-Type, or JSON object has no keys.
```

Answer (score 0):

Found some answer's on Nestjs discord channel.

You had to do following changes:

main.ts

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const adapter = new FastifyAdapter();
  const fastify = adapter.getInstance();

  fastify.addContentTypeParser('multipart', (request, done) => {
    request.isMultipart = true;
    done();
  });
  fastify.addHook('preValidation', async function (request: any, reply) {
    if (!request.raw.isMultipart) {
      return;
    }

    request.body = await processRequest(request.raw, reply.raw);
  });

  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(
    AppModule,
    adapter,
  );


  await app.listen(apiServerPort, apiServerHost);
}

bootstrap();
```

upload.scalar.ts

```
import { Scalar } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { GraphQLUpload } from 'graphql-upload';

@Scalar('Upload')
export class UploadGraphQLScalar {
  protected parseValue(value) {
    return GraphQLUpload.parseValue(value);
  }

  protected serialize(value) {
    return GraphQLUpload.serialize(value);
  }

  protected parseLiteral(ast) {
    return GraphQLUpload.parseLiteral(ast, ast.value);
  }
}
```

users.resolver.ts

```
  @Mutation(() => CreateUsersOutput, {name: 'createUsers'})
  async createUsers(
    @Args('input', new ValidationPipe()) input: CreateUsersInput,
    @ReqUser() reqUser: RequestUser,
  ): Promise<CreateUsersOutput> {
    return this.usersService.createUsers(input, reqUser);
  }
```

create-shared.input.ts

```
@InputType()
export class DataObject {
  @Field(() => UploadGraphQLScalar)
  @Exclude()
  public readonly csv?: Promise<FileUpload>;
}

@InputType()
@ArgsType()
export class CreateUsersInput {
  @Field(() => DataObject)
  public readonly data: DataObject;
}
```

Also, I want to mention you should not use global validation pipes (in my case they made files unreadable)

```
  // app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true }));
```

Answer (score -3):

You could use [graphql-python/gql](https://gql.readthedocs.io/en/v3.0.0rc0/usage/file_upload.html) to try to upload a file:

```py
from gql import Client, gql
from gql.transport.aiohttp import AIOHTTPTransport

transport = AIOHTTPTransport(url='YOUR_URL')

client = Client(transport=transport)

query = gql('''
  mutation($file: Upload!) {
    createUsers(file: $file)
  }
''')

with open("YOUR_FILE_PATH", "rb") as f:

    params = {"file": f}

    result = client.execute(
        query, variable_values=params, upload_files=True
    )

    print(result)
```

If you [activate logging](https://gql.readthedocs.io/en/v3.0.0rc0/advanced/logging.html), you can see some message exchanged between the client and the backend.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have to stick to nestjs so switching to python is not very helpful rn

Comment: Hey the client can be in Python and the backend stays in js. If it works with Python you can use logging to see exactly what is sent and then compare with the data sent by postman